# SQL Inner Join 3 tables

Tags: sql

this is my first time posting here. I'm creating a SQL database with the following relational Schema

---

AUTHOR (Author_ID, Author_Name, Author_Address)

WEBSITE (Website_ID, Web_Name, Server_Capacity, ISP)

COMIC (Comic_ID, Comic_Name, Comic_Date, Author_ID, Website_ID)

```
FK Author_ID → AUTHOR (not Null), (not Unique)
               Delete: C, Update: C

FK Website_ID → WEBSITE (not Null), (not Unique)
               Delete: C, Update: C
```

ISSUE (Issue_ID, Issue_Name, Issue_Date, Comic_ID)

```
FK Comic_ID → COMIC (not Null), (not Unique)
             Delete: C, Update: C
```

PRODUCT (Product_ID, Product_Name, Product_Cost, Comic_ID, Vendor_ID)

FK Comic_ID → COMIC (not Null), (not Unique)
                             Delete: C, Update: C

```
    FK Vendor_ID → VENDOR (not Null), (not Unique)
                         Delete: C, Update: C
```

VENDOR (Vendor_ID, Vendor_Name, Vendor_Address, Website_ID)

```
FK Website_ID → WEBSITE (Null), (not Unique)
                     Delete: N, Update: C
```

CONTRACT (Contract_ID, Contract_Date, Author_ID, Vendor_ID)

```
FK Author_ID → AUTHOR (not Null), (not Unique)
               Delete: C, Update: C

FK Vendor_ID → VENDOR (not Null), (not Unique)
                   Delete: C, Update: C
```

---

I know that's a lot, but there's a specific question in here; I need to create several queries that INNER JOIN 3 tables together. Right now, this is one of the query situations I've created.

"List the name of every website that hosts both a Comic Strip and a Vendor"
to which I've written the following query:

---

SELECT Web_Name FROM Website

INNER JOIN Comic on Website.Website_ID = Comic.Website_ID

INNER JOIN Vendor on Website.Website_ID = Vendor.Website_ID;

---

Does this query properly use the INNER JOIN for 3 tables? should the query situation instead be "list the name of every comic and vendor that shares a website?" I'm a bit lost when it comes to Inner and Outer Joins, so I have trouble with queries that involve them.

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

Your query is going to return every website with both a comic and a vendor . . . but multiple times.  One way to fix it is to add a `distinct`:

```
SELECT distinct w.Web_Name
FROM Website w INNER JOIN
     Comic c
     on w.Website_ID = c.Website_ID inner join
     Vendor v
     on w.Website_ID = w.Website_ID;
```

I've also added aliases to your tables because it makes the query more readable.

There are alternative ways of doing this.  Here is one way:

```
select w.WebName
from Website w
where w.Website_Id in (select WebSite_Id from Comics) and
      w.Website_In in (select WebSite_Id from Vendor)
```

This is saying:  get me all the webnames where the web site is in the list of sites that have a comic and the list of sites that have a vendor.